# What to look for when buying a FiberChannel card?

Tags: linux, centos, storage, lsi

I have a couple of these LSI arrays

```
LSI Model 0834
LSI product name: 1932
LSI Product codename: Mary Jane
Enclosure name: Shea (DM1300)
End of Life: 31-Dec-2010
```

but I can't find any information about the FiberChannel interface is uses to the host. Right now it is connected for a BlueArc Mercury 50 filer, which also is have reached EOL.

**Question**

Can I buy any FC card, or What should I look for, when I want to connect this array to a Linux host?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't contact your local LSI office/partner and ask them.

Comment: They said they can't help me with products that have reached end of life =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off - check vendor recommendations. Some vendors are more scrupulous than others, but they'll generally have a list of 'known compatible' cards.

If you lack this information - as you seem to - I would start with buying Emulex or QLogic HBAs, and avoid anything else unless you have a specific entry in an interoperability matrix.

You will probably need to look as array specific card settings though - whilst they generally work by default, there's a noticeable performance advantage to getting settings/firmware/drivers aligned. (And note - some vendors have specific firmware/drivers that they recommend/support. That's not to say others won't work just fine, but these ones will be the ones they've tested specifically).

More generally:

- always dual path your fiber channel. Ideally with two separate physical cards, going across two completely separate sets of switches.
- keep the cards identical. Firmware, drivers etc. 
  (You can mismatch if you're connecting to different storage infrastructure if you must)

Comment: I definitely recommend qlogic.  And agree check interoperability/compatibility.  Qlogic has some matrices on their site even if the storage vendor may not have it on their site (in this case LSI)

Answer (score 3):

That's actually an LSI Engenio Class 4600 (0834) which was bought by NetApp in 2011 and is no longer available - I was struggling to find documentation either to be honest.

I know some are huge fans of Q-Logic FC HBAs but I'm personally a fan of Emulex ones and although I can't find any form of interoperability matrix for this product I think that if you stick to these manufacturers (or LSI's own of course) you will almost certainly be ok.

Comment: Engenio arrays were sold to OEMs for labeling and support, documentation from the manufacturer always has been a problem. If I am not mistaken, IBM has OEM'd them in their DS4000 line - the asker's variant is likely the DS4700. The [IBM interop matrix](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_storage_disk_ds4000_pdf_interop-matrix.pdf) indeed lists a wealth of OEM'd 4GB QLogic and Emulex HBAs as "compatible".

Comment: Good spot - so I know IBM rebadge NetApp filers but I didn't know they did that product set, sounds good

Comment: I am a huge fan of qlogic and not a big fan of emulex.  I have had emulex issues in the past going way back which could influence my decision that I rather not work with them.  Qlogic has top rate driver support and customer support and utility and tool support.  I haven't checked in awhile but Emulex is usually 50% to 70% of the cost of Qlogic so if you are on a budget, I do agree that Emulex and Qlogic are the top two.  I would still consider Qlogic.  Also do your best to check interoperability/compatibility. Even if not on LSI's site, Qlogic has a well developed compatibility matrix.

Comment: @Chopper3 On the back is says "class 3600" instead of "class 4600". Does that change anything?